# How to close program if , if else ,equals no

Tags: c#

I just started C#.
I can't seem to find a way of the program closing it if the, if else, equals no.

I've tried :

```
-> System.Environment.Exit(1);
-> public static void Exit ();
```

A part of the Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Jes/No");

string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (input == "Jes")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Apex Libary");
}
if (input == "No")
{
    ________________________
}
```

The Blanks :______________ , are a space holder so that I know where to put the code.

Comment: I would try to avoid needing to use `System.Exit` at all. Instead, declare your `Main` method to return an `int`, and then just return 1 from the "No" branch.

Comment: This can be achieved by the code path

Answer (score 1):

Use :

`Environment.Exit(0);`

This command is used to close the application by providing an exit code.